# How to make token authentication in Codeigniter 3 REST API

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So i just finished making REST API in Codeigniter 3 and i wanted to make an authentication with token, so i used the JWT from this repo `https://github.com/ParitoshVaidya/CodeIgniter-JWT-Sample/tree/CI3`
My question is, how do i make my API Controller to require the token for every request ?
This is my api controller

```
function __construct($config = 'rest') {
        parent::__construct($config);   
        $this->load->helper(array('text','url'));
        $this->load->model('Api_model');        
    }
    
    // GET ARTICLE
    function index_get(){
        $data = $this->Api_model->get_all_article();
        return $this->response($data,200);
    }
```

and this is my token controller

```
public function token_get()
    {
        $tokenData = array();
        $tokenData['id'] = 1;        
        $output['token'] = AUTHORIZATION::generateToken($tokenData);
        $this->set_response($output, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend moving the token-logic into a library. Then you'll have it available in all controllers and do not have to do a dirty instanciating of a controller inside your api controller.

Add class **application\libraries\Token.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Token {

        public function token_get()
        {
                $tokenData = array();
                $tokenData['id'] = 1;        
                $output['token'] = AUTHORIZATION::generateToken($tokenData);
                $this->set_response($output, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // <--
        }
}
```

You will have to make this `REST_Controller` available in your library or change this logic accordingly.

Then in your **APIController**:

```
function token_get(){
    $this->load->library('Token');
    return $this->Token->token_get();
}

// GET ARTICLE
function index_get(){
    $token = $this->token_get(); // added this line
    $data = $this->Api_model->get_all_article();
    return $this->response($data,200);
}
```

Read more about [Libraries in CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html)